# Libraries that recognize and fit hand-drawn shape into perfect shapes

Tags: algorithm, graphics, touch, shapes, gesture

I am trying to implement a simple feature (any language is fine) to recognize and fit perfect shapes (rectangle, triangle, circle, etc.) from hand-drawn sketched shapes. There are many existing tools support that, for example, [Procreate's QuickShape](https://procreate.art/handbook/procreate/guides/quickshape/), Apple Notes App which can automatically convert your drawing into a perfect shape, etc. Other works recognize the shape categories easily, like the [$1 recognizer](http://depts.washington.edu/acelab/proj/dollar/index.html), but cannot provide a fit perfect shape but only the category. I believe this is a well-researched topic and there must be a library or algorithm that could do that, given any sequence of touch locations [(x,y)]. Can anyone help me find that or tell me where to start? Thanks!